# Contract still valid after servicer changed name?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, california

There is no clause in the contract about transfer of service (or whatever you call it) like if it's still enforceable even after the service has been transferred to someone else.

I had a contract with a company, but that company changed its name. Is my contract still enforceable?

Comment: If a name change allowed someone to get out of a contract, then all homeowners would change their names immediately after mortgaging their properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I had a contract with a company, but that company changed its name. Is
>   my contract still enforceable?

Yes, because what matters is the entity itself. A contract is not stricken merely because one or more parties changed names or labels.

Comment: Sounds correct -- imagine a wedding caterer trying to collect payment after brides change their names. One other thing to be aware of, though, is that the entity did not simply change its name, but has rather been acquired by a new entity or spun off from the original. In that case, depending on the type of contract, there may be a change in the parties' ability to enforce the contract.

Comment: @bdb484 "*the entity did not simply change its name, but has rather been acquired by a new entity or spun off from the original*" A company acquisition, merger, or split does not extinguish obligations with respect to third parties such as the OP. What might change, though, is *from which entity* the OP should pursue recovery. "*there may be a change in the parties' ability to enforce the contract.*" Yes, but I think that would happen only in extreme scenarios such as bankruptcy of the entity that breached the contract, regardless of the type of that contract and of the type of acquisition.